# Transform an `as const` object to a more generalized type

Tags: typescript, typescript-utility

## Derive generalized type/interface from `as const` const object

I have this:

```
const usersDefaultValues = {
  firstName: '',
  isGuest: false
} as const
```

And I want to derive this type:

```
type DefaultValuesSchema = {
  firstName: string
  isGuest: boolean
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for smth like this:

```js
const usersDefaultValues = {
  firstName: '',
  isGuest: false
} as const

type M<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends boolean ? boolean : T[P] extends string ? string : never;
}

type Result = M<typeof usersDefaultValues>
```